# How do I parse UTC and format to local time with Clojure's clojure.java-time library?

Tags: clojure, java-time

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. The goal is to parse a string such as "20230227T010000Z" and then to print out the time in the local time zone.

```
(as-> "20230227T010000Z" X                        
      (jt/offset-date-time "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssX" X) ;#object[java.time.OffsetDateTime "0xf79e8a9" "2023-02-27T01:00Z"]
      (jt/with-offset X (jt/zone-offset))          ;#object[java.time.OffsetDateTime "0x41ec977e" "2023-02-27T01:00-05:00"]     
      (jt/format "hh:mm" X))                       ;"01:00"
```

This returns "01:00" even though `(jt/zone-offset)` returns "-05:00".

Comment: You may also be interested in this library of helper functions:  https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/22.08.03/api/tupelo.java-time

Comment: In `(jt/format "hh:mm" X))` you may wnatr upper case `HH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using the correct function:

[`with-offset`](https://dm3.github.io/clojure.java-time/java-time.api.html#var-with-offset)

> Sets the offset to the specified value ensuring that the local time stays the same.

```
(as-> "20230227T010000Z" X
      (jt/offset-date-time "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssX" X) 
      (jt/with-offset X -5)         
      (jt/format "hh:mm" X))
=> "01:00"
```

[`with-offset-same-instant`](https://dm3.github.io/clojure.java-time/java-time.api.html#var-with-offset-same-instant)

> Sets the offset to the specified value ensuring that the result has the same instant.

```
(as-> "20230227T010000Z" X
      (jt/offset-date-time "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssX" X) 
      (jt/with-offset-same-instant X -5)         
      (jt/format "hh:mm" X))
=> "08:00"
```